# Mono: DateTime serialization and decimal serialization errors

Tags: .net, serialization, mono, xamarin.ios

I have problems during serialization/deserialization.

I'm using a WCF service (that used .NET framework) and a client created in Mono.

The client calls the service and it receives **DateTime** objects. This is the error:

```
Exception in async operation: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Value -8588999498056367604 is outside the valid range [0,3155378975999999999].
Parameter name: ticks
```

The other problem is the following.

The client calls an other service and retrieves a **decimal** value. When I run the call, the client breaks down and fires this exception:

```
System.NotImplementedException: ValueType 148 on node Text
  at System.Xml.XmlBinaryDictionaryReader+NodeInfo.get_Value () [0x001e8] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System.Runtime.Serialization/System.Xml/XmlBinaryDictionaryReader.cs:191
```

How is it possible to fix these problems? Thank you.

Comment: It would help to know which version of Mono you are using

Comment: Thank you for the reply. How can I retrieve the Mono version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first problem, check this post:

http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/mono-bugs/2010-December/107338.html

What is the DateTime kind? If it is Utc or Local, try sending a DateTime with DateTimeKind.Unspecified and see if you have the same issue. If so, I think you are bumping up against this bug: https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=660424

You could test if the same issue exists in the current Mono master. Another workaround could be to just to send the DateTime as a long, and then reconstruct it on the client.

Your second problem I'm not so sure: the stack seems to reference MonoTouch? Are you running this on iPhone? A complete code sample would help here.

Comment: In that case, how is your WCF service exposed? I might recommend you try calling it using the traditional web services stack. MonoTouch is still based on Mono 2.6 where the WCF implementation is not very mature.

Comment: Thank you for your collaboration...What do you mean with "how is your WCF service exposed"? I'm using a svc file created with VS (slutil.exe) and imported in my Monotouch project...maybe traditional web services stack are more complicated...

Comment: I mean how the service is hosted (HTTP, TCP, how it is secured, etc). If it is hosted as an BasicHttpBinding you should be able to use the traditional web services stack (System.Web.Services) to access it which will probably be more stable on MonoTouch.